# How to put two inputs into tensorflow lambda layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lambda, concatenation

How do you put two inputs into tensorflow lambda layer? I have tried:

```
channel_input=Input(shape=(4,),dtype='complex64',name='channel_input')

...
realed_ffted_channel1 = Dense(2*N_c,activation='relu')(realed_ffted_channel)
precoded_data = Lambda(lambda x,y: tf.concat([x,y],1))([encoding_x,realed_ffted_channel1])
```

However, I receive this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-9332eac3e7cf> in <module>()
     10 
     11 #Precoding Encoder
---> 12 precoded_data = Lambda(lambda x,y: tf.concat([x,y],1))([encoding_x,realed_ffted_channel1])
     13 encoder_data = Dense(3*N_c,activation='relu')(precoded_data)
     14 encoder_data1 = Dense(N_c,activation='relu')(encoder_data)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/core.py in call(self, inputs, mask, training)
    820       arguments['training'] = training
    821     with variable_scope.variable_creator_scope(self._variable_creator):
--> 822       return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
    823 
    824   def _variable_creator(self, next_creator, **kwargs):

TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

implying the second input `y` was not passed.

Comment: I do not recall, but I believe the lambda takes only a single argument here. Try doing `lambda xy: tf.concat(*xy,1)`

Comment: Sadly, It didn't work. hmm, then we cannot use two inputs in a layer???

Comment: Do `lambda xy: tf.concat(xy, 1)`. The inputs are received as a list containing what you passed in. Also, consider using a [`Concatenate`](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#concatenate) layer if that is all your layer does.

Comment: Thank you a lot . it works with tf.concat. But it doesn't work with similar code like ```conved_data = Lambda(lambda x,y: conv_channel(x,y))(iffted_encoded_data,channel_input)``` i changed this to ```conved_data = Lambda(lambda xy: conv_channel(xy))(iffted_encoded_data,channel_input)```  but not working

Comment: @이홍재 In that case it would be `lambda xy: conv_channel(xy[0], xy[1])`, or `lambda xy: conv_channel(*xy)`. `xy` here is a list, you have to use its contents accordingly. `tf.concat` receives a list as a parameter, so you can pass `xy` directly, or `[xy[0], xy[1]]` if you prefer, but `conv_channel` takes two parameters, you need to explicitly unpack them form `xy`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
precoded_data = Lambda(lambda x: tf.concat([x[0], x[1]],1))([encoding_x,realed_ffted_channel1])
```

Note that for this specific use case you can just also use the `Concatenate` layer.

Comment: Why `Lambda(lambda x, y: tf.concat([x, y],1))(encoding_x,realed_ffted_channel1)` crashes?

Comment: @MeysamSadeghi I cannot guess what is wrong, you did not provide any context, please ask your own question instead of commenting.

Comment: I meant in your answer, you use the keras Lambda function with a python lambda that has one input argument (i.e. a list), and take the two inputs as parts of the list (`x[0], x[1]`). My question was, why you do not use a python lambda function with two inputs instead? Like `Lambda(lambda x, y: tf.concat([x, y],1))(encoding_x,realed_ffted_channel1)`, instead of `Lambda(lambda x: tf.concat([x[0], x[1]],1))([encoding_x,realed_ffted_channel1])`? I see that my suggestion crashes and do not work. but I do not understand why?

Comment: @MeysamSadeghi Same answer as the previous comment, ask your own question.