# Multiple Inputs to Lambda Layer Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to make an extremely simple example of an adder (adding together two scaler tensors) within a lambda layer in keras/tensorflow. Here is my minimal example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

def adder(x1,x2):
  return tf.math.add(x1,x2)
```

I can perform a quick test of my adder function:

```
# Check that the adder function works well for two scaler tensors
scaler1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(21.1)
scaler2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(12.0)
print(adder(scaler1,scaler2))
```

Which gets the correct output:

```
tf.Tensor(33.1, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

So I now define a multi-input keras network with one lambda layer which tries to add the two inputs together:

```
inpAdder1 = keras.layers.Input((1), name="Input1")
inpAdder2 = keras.layers.Input((1), name="Input2")
doAdd = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: adder(x[0],x[1]),name="LambdaLayer")([inpAdder1,inpAdder2])

modelAdder = keras.Model([inpAdder1,inpAdder2],doAdd)
```

The network summary appears correct:

```
Model: "model_12"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
Input1 (InputLayer)             [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Input2 (InputLayer)             [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
LambdaLayer (Lambda)            (None, 1)            0           Input1[0][0]                     
                                                                 Input2[0][0]                     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---

But if I try to call a simple predict with the same scaler tensors, I get an error which I'm not sure how to debug:

```
modelAdder.predict([scaler1, scaler2])
```

Error traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-4319124675560319> in <module>
     16 print(adder(scaler1,scaler2))
     17 
---> 18 modelAdder.predict([scaler1, scaler2])

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1718                         '. Consider setting it to AutoShardPolicy.DATA.')
   1719 
-> 1720       data_handler = data_adapter.get_data_handler(
   1721           x=x,
   1722           batch_size=batch_size,

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in get_data_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1381   if getattr(kwargs["model"], "_cluster_coordinator", None):
   1382     return _ClusterCoordinatorDataHandler(*args, **kwargs)
-> 1383   return DataHandler(*args, **kwargs)
   1384 
   1385 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model, steps_per_execution, distribute)
   1136 
   1137     adapter_cls = select_data_adapter(x, y)
-> 1138     self._adapter = adapter_cls(
   1139         x,
   1140         y,

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, sample_weight_modes, batch_size, epochs, steps, shuffle, **kwargs)
    238     inputs = pack_x_y_sample_weight(x, y, sample_weights)
    239 
--> 240     num_samples = set(int(i.shape[0]) for i in tf.nest.flatten(inputs)).pop()
    241     _check_data_cardinality(inputs)
    242 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    238     inputs = pack_x_y_sample_weight(x, y, sample_weights)
    239 
--> 240     num_samples = set(int(i.shape[0]) for i in tf.nest.flatten(inputs)).pop()
    241     _check_data_cardinality(inputs)
    242 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    894       else:
    895         if self._v2_behavior:
--> 896           return self._dims[key].value
    897         else:
    898           return self._dims[key]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've got a feeling I'm missing something easy here but I've tried looking at similar questions (for example: [How to put two inputs into tensorflow lambda layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59845217/how-to-put-two-inputs-into-tensorflow-lambda-layer)), and can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further debugging, I have solved the issue. The issue is because I have not included a batch dimension when calling the model.predict function.

Changing the predict line above to:

```
modelAdder.predict([tf.expand_dims(scaler1,0), tf.expand_dims(scaler2,0)])
```

Solves the issue by adding an extra dimension to each tensor for the batch. The resulting tensor from the above command is:

```
Out[48]: array([[33.1]], dtype=float32)
```